# Need to redirect all non www to www and all https to subdomain

Tags: mod-rewrite

Having trouble writing this compound rewrite containing the following rules:

**Requirements:**

- Redirect all http://example.com -> http://www.example.com
- Redirect all https://* -> http://wwws.*
- Enforce all /checkout/* page to use https:

E.G.

http://example.com/checkout/123 -> https://wwws.example.com/checkout/123 
or http://example.com/checkout ->https://wwws.example.com/checkout/123

**What i have currently done:**

I currently have a series of rewrites that rewrites the non-www to the www:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is problematic because when a http request for the URI: http://wwws.example.com it redirects that to http://www.wwws.example.com.

How would i achieve a rewrite that would satisfied my requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use HTTP_HOST:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^!example.com$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

My preference is for this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.*$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^/.+www\/(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or much simplier:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
ServerAlias example.com  
RedirectMatch permanent ^/(.*) http://www.example.com/$1  
</VirtualHost>
```

Exercice left to the read: find more other ways.

To redirect https to http:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^80$  
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,R]
```

Or:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP} off  
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Which is the most simple manner of doing so?